# When a radio button is clicked how to get a value from a form using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying alert a username when a radio button is clicked, however when a radio button is clicked the first username always alerts instead of the associated username.

The result should be the following:

Jack445 
  - if user's radio button is clicked alert "Jack445"

Doe445
  - if user's radio button is clicked alert "Doe445"

John445
  - if user's radio button is clicked alert "John445"

-

However the result I am getting is the following:

Jack445 
  - if user's radio button is clicked alert "Jack445"

Doe445
  - if user's radio button is clicked alert "Jack445"

John445
  - if user's radio button is clicked alert "Jack445"

```js
$('.star_form > .star_rating').each(function() {
  $(this).click(function() {
    alert($(this).parent().children().closest('.rated_username').val());
  });
});
```

```css
.stars {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.stars .username {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: Tahoma;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="user_container">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="stars" id="stars_1">
      <div class="username">Jack445</div>
      <form class="star_form" id="star_form_1" onsubmit="return false;" role="form">
        <input class="star star-5 star_rating" id="star-5" type="radio" name="star" value="5">
        <label class="star star-5" for="star-5">5</label>
        <input class="star star-4 star_rating" id="star-4" type="radio" name="star" value="4">
        <label class="star star-4" for="star-4">4</label>
        <input class="star star-3 star_rating" id="star-3" type="radio" name="star" value="3">
        <label class="star star-3" for="star-3">3</label>
        <input class="star star-2 star_rating" id="star-2" type="radio" name="star" value="2">
        <label class="star star-2" for="star-2">2</label>
        <input class="star star-1 star_rating" id="star-1" type="radio" name="star" value="1">
        <label class="star star-1" for="star-1">1</label>
        <input type="hidden" class="rated_username" value="Jack445">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="user_container">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="stars" id="stars_1">
      <div class="username">Doe445</div>
      <form class="star_form" id="star_form_1" onsubmit="return false;" role="form">
        <input class="star star-5 star_rating" id="star-5" type="radio" name="star" value="5">
        <label class="star star-5" for="star-5">5</label>
        <input class="star star-4 star_rating" id="star-4" type="radio" name="star" value="4">
        <label class="star star-4" for="star-4">4</label>
        <input class="star star-3 star_rating" id="star-3" type="radio" name="star" value="3">
        <label class="star star-3" for="star-3">3</label>
        <input class="star star-2 star_rating" id="star-2" type="radio" name="star" value="2">
        <label class="star star-2" for="star-2">2</label>
        <input class="star star-1 star_rating" id="star-1" type="radio" name="star" value="1">
        <label class="star star-1" for="star-1">1</label>
        <input type="hidden" class="rated_username" value="Doe445">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="user_container">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="stars" id="stars_1">
      <div class="username">John445</div>
      <form class="star_form" id="star_form_1" onsubmit="return false;" role="form">
        <input class="star star-5 star_rating" id="star-5" type="radio" name="star" value="5">
        <label class="star star-5" for="star-5">5</label>
        <input class="star star-4 star_rating" id="star-4" type="radio" name="star" value="4">
        <label class="star star-4" for="star-4">4</label>
        <input class="star star-3 star_rating" id="star-3" type="radio" name="star" value="3">
        <label class="star star-3" for="star-3">3</label>
        <input class="star star-2 star_rating" id="star-2" type="radio" name="star" value="2">
        <label class="star star-2" for="star-2">2</label>
        <input class="star star-1 star_rating" id="star-1" type="radio" name="star" value="1">
        <label class="star star-1" for="star-1">1</label>
        <input type="hidden" class="rated_username" value="John445">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces your problem.

Comment: It´s working, what´s wrong?

Comment: Are you using IE? In Chrome it works.

Comment: @zer00ne I'm using chrome I keep getting the first username

Comment: You can't have duplicated ids. change the id patterns Ex. `id="starA-1"` next group can be `id="starB-1"` etc. What happens is that the browser will stop at the first id it finds and doesn't continue because it thinks there's only one id because ids are unique. This behavior is warranted because it's up to the developer to ensure that an id is never duplicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Fix

1. IDs must be unique.

   **Fix** - All radio ids plus some div now have unique IDs.
2. A group of radio buttons should share the same `[name]` attribute so that they have a mutually exclusive relationship. Do not share the the same `[name]` between radio groups. Give each radio group a unique `[name]` attribute to share.

   **Fix** - Gave each of the radio groups a unique `[name]`
3. Use one `<form>`. A `<form>` will gather the values of all form controls that have a `[name]` attribute. A radio group that shares a `[name]` will have the value of the selected radio button only.

   **Fix** - Removed all of the `<form>`s and placed a single `<form>` wraped around everything.

   **Bonus** - The `<form>` upon being submitted, will send the form data to a live test server. The response will be displayed in an `<iframe>` below.
4. jQuery line by line:

   - The `form#starRating` delegates the `change` event to each `:radio`

     ```
     $('#starRating').on('change', ':radio', function(e) {
     ```
   - Get the value of the `:radio'` that changed.

     ```
     var rating = $(this).val();
     ```
   - Log the value (BTW use the `console` don't use `alert()`)

     ```
     console.log(rating);
     ```
   - Find the changed `:radio` sibling element with the class `.rated_username` and store its value in a variable.

     ```
     var user = $(this).siblings('.rated_username').val();
     ```
   - I repeat **do not use alert()** use `console.log` or `console.dir`

     ```
     console.log(user);
      });
     ```

**Note:** Below the following Demo are some references.

### Demo

```js
$('#starRating').on('change', ':radio', function(e) {
  var rating = $(this).val();
  console.log(rating);
  var user = $(this).siblings('.rated_username').val();
  console.log(user);
});
```

```css
.stars {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.stars .username {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: Tahoma;
}

[type=submit] {
  float: right;
  font: inherit
}


/* For demonstration only */

.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 240px;
  max-width: 180px;
  transform: translate(250px, -100px);
  color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id='starRating' action='https://httpbin.org/post' method='post' target='view'>
  <div class="user_container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="stars" id="stars_1">
        <div class="username">Jack445</div>

        <input class="star star-5 star_rating" id="star-5A" type="radio" name="star1" value="5">
        <label class="star star-5" for="star-5A">5</label>
        <input class="star star-4 star_rating" id="star-4A" type="radio" name="star1" value="4">
        <label class="star star-4" for="star-4A">4</label>
        <input class="star star-3 star_rating" id="star-3A" type="radio" name="star1" value="3">
        <label class="star star-3" for="star-3A">3</label>
        <input class="star star-2 star_rating" id="star-2A" type="radio" name="star1" value="2">
        <label class="star star-2" for="star-2A">2</label>
        <input class="star star-1 star_rating" id="star-1A" type="radio" name="star1" value="1">
        <label class="star star-1" for="star-1A">1</label>
        <input type="hidden" class="rated_username" value="Jack445">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="user_container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="stars" id="stars_2">
        <div class="username">Doe445</div>

        <input class="star star-5 star_rating" id="star-5B" type="radio" name="star2" value="5">
        <label class="star star-5" for="star-5B">5</label>
        <input class="star star-4 star_rating" id="star-4B" type="radio" name="star2" value="4">
        <label class="star star-4" for="star-4B">4</label>
        <input class="star star-3 star_rating" id="star-3B" type="radio" name="star2" value="3">
        <label class="star star-3" for="star-3B">3</label>
        <input class="star star-2 star_rating" id="star-2B" type="radio" name="star2" value="2">
        <label class="star star-2" for="star-2B">2</label>
        <input class="star star-1 star_rating" id="star-1B" type="radio" name="star2" value="1">
        <label class="star star-1" for="star-1B">1</label>
        <input type="hidden" class="rated_username" value="Doe445">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="user_container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="stars" id="stars_3">
        <div class="username">John445</div>

        <input class="star star-5 star_rating" id="star-5C" type="radio" name="star3" value="5">
        <label class="star star-5" for="star-5C">5</label>
        <input class="star star-4 star_rating" id="star-4C" type="radio" name="star3" value="4">
        <label class="star star-4" for="star-4C">4</label>
        <input class="star star-3 star_rating" id="star-3C" type="radio" name="star3" value="3">
        <label class="star star-3" for="star-3C">3</label>
        <input class="star star-2 star_rating" id="star-2C" type="radio" name="star3" value="2">
        <label class="star star-2" for="star-2C">2</label>
        <input class="star star-1 star_rating" id="star-1C" type="radio" name="star3" value="1">
        <label class="star star-1" for="star-1C">1</label>
        <input type="hidden" class="rated_username" value="John445">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type='submit'>
  <iframe name='view' src='about:blank' width='98%'></iframe>
```

### References

- **[`siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)**
- **[Defining a Radio Group](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio#Defining_a_radio_group)**
- jQuery **[`.change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/)** (or **[.on`('change'...`)](https://api.jquery.com/change/#entry-longdesc)** event handler
- jQuery [**`:radio` Selector**](https://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/)

Comment: I understand placing everything is one form no problem, but will it not work at all if there's multiple forms?

Comment: Yes it would work with multiple forms, but the natural assumption is if there's a form, it is presented to the user as one form. In fact now that I think about it, I haven't seen any sites that have multiple forms on a page. Is there a reason why you need multiple forms? Normally the purpose of a form is to provide an interface for a user to send data to a server.

Comment: makes perfect sense and you're 100% right. Your method works! Thank you for educating me on that.

Comment: That's great, I'm glad I could help. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. `div`'s dont have values. they contain text.

```js
$('.star_form > .star_rating').each(function() {
  $(this).click(function() {
    alert($(this).parent().parent().closest('div').find('.username').text());
  });
});
```

```css
.stars {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.stars .username {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: Tahoma;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="user_container">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="stars" id="stars_1">
      <div class="username">Jack445</div>
      <form class="star_form" id="star_form_1" onsubmit="return false;" role="form">
        <input class="star star-5 star_rating" id="star-5" type="radio" name="star" value="5">
        <label class="star star-5" for="star-5">5</label>
        <input class="star star-4 star_rating" id="star-4" type="radio" name="star" value="4">
        <label class="star star-4" for="star-4">4</label>
        <input class="star star-3 star_rating" id="star-3" type="radio" name="star" value="3">
        <label class="star star-3" for="star-3">3</label>
        <input class="star star-2 star_rating" id="star-2" type="radio" name="star" value="2">
        <label class="star star-2" for="star-2">2</label>
        <input class="star star-1 star_rating" id="star-1" type="radio" name="star" value="1">
        <label class="star star-1" for="star-1">1</label>
        <input type="hidden" class="rated_username" value="Jack445">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="user_container">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="stars" id="stars_1">
      <div class="username">Doe445</div>
      <form class="star_form" id="star_form_1" onsubmit="return false;" role="form">
        <input class="star star-5 star_rating" id="star-5" type="radio" name="star" value="5">
        <label class="star star-5" for="star-5">5</label>
        <input class="star star-4 star_rating" id="star-4" type="radio" name="star" value="4">
        <label class="star star-4" for="star-4">4</label>
        <input class="star star-3 star_rating" id="star-3" type="radio" name="star" value="3">
        <label class="star star-3" for="star-3">3</label>
        <input class="star star-2 star_rating" id="star-2" type="radio" name="star" value="2">
        <label class="star star-2" for="star-2">2</label>
        <input class="star star-1 star_rating" id="star-1" type="radio" name="star" value="1">
        <label class="star star-1" for="star-1">1</label>
        <input type="hidden" class="rated_username" value="Doe445">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="user_container">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="stars" id="stars_1">
      <div class="username">John445</div>
      <form class="star_form" id="star_form_1" onsubmit="return false;" role="form">
        <input class="star star-5 star_rating" id="star-5" type="radio" name="star" value="5">
        <label class="star star-5" for="star-5">5</label>
        <input class="star star-4 star_rating" id="star-4" type="radio" name="star" value="4">
        <label class="star star-4" for="star-4">4</label>
        <input class="star star-3 star_rating" id="star-3" type="radio" name="star" value="3">
        <label class="star star-3" for="star-3">3</label>
        <input class="star star-2 star_rating" id="star-2" type="radio" name="star" value="2">
        <label class="star star-2" for="star-2">2</label>
        <input class="star star-1 star_rating" id="star-1" type="radio" name="star" value="1">
        <label class="star star-1" for="star-1">1</label>
        <input type="hidden" class="rated_username" value="John445">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```